# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wait_on_rate_limit_notify'

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to make an auto reply bot tweepy

```
import tweepy
import time

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('xxxx',
                           'xxxx')
auth.set_access_token('xxxx',
                      'xxxx')


api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
search = 'NFT'
numero = 50

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items(numero):
        print("nome do usuario: @" + tweet.user.screen_name)
        api.update_status("@" + tweet.user.screen_name + " NFT GIVEAWAY (0.5 ETH FLOOR) Steps: 1. Follow @GiovanniC_NFT 2. Like and retweet! 3. Follow https://instagram.com/gi.ovannicorrea/ 3. Tag a friend! winner announced in 4 days #NFT #NFTCommunity #NFTGiveaways #NFTdrops", in_reply_to_status_id=tweet.id)
        print("correto")
        time.sleep(30)
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print(e.reason)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Bu im getting error TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wait_on_rate_limit_notify' can someone help me ?

Comment: Always post full Traceback errors.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This error means that ```tweepy.API()``` doesn't have a ```wait_on_rate_limit_notify``` kwarg parameter as mentioned in the doc: https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html

Comment: What can i do ?

Comment: Trivially, don't use words which don't mean anything. More ideally, explain what you wanted those words to mean, and show us why you thought `wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True` would mean that.